# Dependency relying on older Webpack version breaking ESLint testing

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, eslint

I have a project that uses Webpack for bundling and ESLint for code quality. I just upgraded from Webpack 4.35.2 to version 5.64.2, which seems to have broken the ESLint test.
The project has a third-party dependency that itself uses Webpack v3 and relies on `NamedModulesPlugin` which existed in that version. This was still present in v4 but removed from v5 and I now get the error `TypeError: webpack.NamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor` when running the ESLint test.

Obviously, the dependency is not using version 3 as specified in its own `package.json` but rather the version of the main project. This is clearly very wrong and I don't understand how this is even meant to work.
I'm using [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import) and `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` to resolve the import statements in my source files and I guess that simply doesn't handle incompatible versions of the same package used across the dependency tree? Everything works fine when running and building the project.

I'm at a loss as to how I can resolve this or work around it so if anyone has any pointers I would greatly appreciate it!